# flink when to use timewindowAll

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a pipeline that consumes data with the following shape :
`case class Foo(source: String, destination: String){def key=source+destination}` I want to remove all `source+destination` duplicates that arrive in the same hour and then I want to count all calls that arrives for a destination in the same hour. I created a pipeline with a `src ~> timewindow1(1 hour, keyBy:key) ~>  timewindow2(1 hour, keyBy:destination) ~> ...` should I use `timewindowAll` in timewindow2 ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `timeWindowAll` in cases where you don't want to have key-partitioned windowing. Since you are keying by destination, you should use `timeWindow`, not `timeWindowAll`.